# Bind Selective Data in data list From database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, datalist

I am creating a page where we can select ID from a grid view by checking on check-boxes placed in the grid-view and then by binding them in the  data-list and print those selective ID's. My problem is that i cannot bind the selective id's together in the Data list, only the last one fetched is bound in the Data list. Here is my code.

`<asp:DataList ID="DlIdcard" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Caption="The Muscle gym" CellPadding="5" 
            CellSpacing="5" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatColumns="2" 
            ToolTip="ID Card Print" Width="70%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width: 393px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../Images/icongym.png" 
                    style="height: 50px; width: 50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style54">
                            <asp:Label ID="gymname" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" 
                                Text="The Muscle Gym"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style57">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                            &nbsp;:</td>
                        <td class="style56">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmemname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style57">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Address :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style56">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmemadd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MemberAdd") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style57">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Mobile :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style56">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmemmob" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MemberMobileNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style57">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Emergency Contact  :"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style57">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblemercontct" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%#Eval("EmerContctName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="emrgncycntctnumbr" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("EmerContctNum") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBatchname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BatchName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            &nbsp;:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblstarttime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StartTime") %>'></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Lblendtime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EndTime") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Expiry Date :" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblexpdate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PackageExpDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorStyle BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="2px" />
        </asp:DataList>`

and here is the code behind

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvshortdetail.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk!=null && chk.Checked)
            {
                pid = gvshortdetail.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                //pid += (gvrow.Cells[1].Text) + "*";
                chkcntr += 1;

                OleDbDataAdapter dacon = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches.BatchID, dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches.MemberID, dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberName,  dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberMobileNo, dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberAdd, dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.EmerContctName, dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.EmerContctNum, Convert(varchar,dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.PackageExpDate,3)as PackageExpDate, dbo.Wc_Batches.BatchName, dbo.Wc_Batches.StartTime,  dbo.Wc_Batches.EndTime FROM    dbo.Wc_Batches INNER JOIN dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches ON dbo.Wc_Batches.BatchID = dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches.BatchID INNER JOIN  dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication ON dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches.MemberID = dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberID  ORDER BY MemberID DESC ", ConnectionManager.con);
                DataSet dscon = new DataSet();
                dacon.Fill(dscon);
                DlIdcard.DataSource = dscon;
                DlIdcard.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Your query to fill the `OleDbDataAdapter` seems to be independent of anything inside the loop. Can you explain a bit more about that query

Comment: dbo.Wc_MemberAssignedBatches.MemberID = dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberID WHERE dbo.WcApp_MemberApplication.MemberID='"+pid+"'ORDER BY MemberID DESC ", ConnectionManager.con);'